# installing a specific version of GCC compiler onto a nvidia:cuda docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gcc

I'm trying to create an environment with cuda 8, cudnn 5.1, and GCC 5.3 but I can't install gcc by apt install gcc-5.3, is there any way to do so?
I have tried apt install gcc-5.3 and using conda to install gcc_linux-64 both not working.